# Displaying repetitive html element with conditional value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have many bootstrap badge with different color displayed in a table column. This badge will be displayed if the value exist. The badge is different in class name and style name using different color for every badge. I think the html element is repetitive. Is there anyway I can reuse the element  or make my code simpler?

```
        <td className="text-nowrap">
          {asset.kfc && (
            <span className="badge badge-primary">Kentucky Fried Chicken</span>
          )}{' '}
          {asset.mcd && (
            <span className="badge badge-success">Mc Donald</span>
          )}{' '}
          {asset.sub && (
            <span className="badge badge-danger">Subway</span>
          )}{' '}
          {asset.dom && (
            <span className="badge" style={{backgroundColor: 'pink'}} >Domino</span>
          )}{' '}
          {asset.krg && (
            <span className="badge" style={{backgroundColor: 'cyan'}} >Kenny Rogers Roasters</span>
          )}{' '}
        </td>
```

I have 9 of these badges. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean every span tag is a badge?

Comment: @HemadriDasari yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the title and the class name of each span in a variable, here, `obj`. 
And assuming that assest is an object, map over the keys to return span containing.

```
    var obj = {
        kfc: {title: 'Kentucky Fried Chicken', class: 'badge-primary'},
        mcd: {title: 'KMc Donald', class: 'badge-primary'},
        sub: {title: 'Subway', class: 'badge-primary'} 
    }

    Object.keys(asset).map(key=>(
        { assest[key] &&
            <span className={'badge '+obj[key].class} >{obj[key].title}</span>
        }
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested. Here's the solution:

```
  const obj = {
    kfc: {title: 'Kentucky Fried Chicken', class: 'badge-primary'},
    mcd: {title: 'Mc Donald', class: 'badge-success'},
    sub: {title: 'Subway', class: 'badge-danger'},
    pzh: {title: 'Pizza Hut', color: 'cyan'},
    dom: {title: 'Domino Pizza', color: 'pink'},
  };

  const badgeElem = asset =>
    Object.keys(obj).map(
      key =>
        asset[key] && (
          <Fragment>
            <span
              className={`badge ${obj[key].class}`}
              style={{backgroundColor: obj[key].color}}>
              {obj[key].title}
            </span>{' '}
          </Fragment>
        ),
    );
```

Table code:

```
<td className="text-nowrap">{badgeElem(asset)}</td>
```

[image]